# connecting to a localhost server in c# app from a firefox extension

Tags: c#, javascript, sockets

I am using a firefox extension, that checks each time when a new page loads, and when it does, it sends a handshake request to a web server I have in my C# program. My problem is that the server never receives the request. Can someone point me in the right direction since I think I am doing something wrong. Thanks

```
function examplePageLoad(event) {

  if (event.originalTarget instanceof HTMLDocument) {

    var win = event.originalTarget.defaultView;

    if (win.frameElement) {


  var socket = new WebSocket('127.0.0.1:13000');
        socket.onopen = function() {
            alert('handshake successfully established. May send data now...');
        };
        socket.onclose = function() {
            alert('connection closed');
        };
    }

  }

}


window.addEventListener("load", function () {

  gBrowser.addEventListener("load", examplePageLoad, true);

}, false);
```

And in C#:

```
 public void acceptClient()
        {
            TcpListener server = null;
            try
            {
                // Set the TcpListener on port 13000.
                Int32 port = 13000;
                IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

                // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
                server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

                // Start listening for client requests.
                server.Start();

                // Buffer for reading data
                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];


                // Enter the listening loop.
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

                    // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                    // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
                    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                    Console.WriteLine("Event was fired!");


                    UserModel um = new UserModel();

                    um.maintainUserModel(); //method uses to maintain user model

                }
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Stop listening for new clients.
                server.Stop();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which IP do you use in the browser to get to that page? Loopback or the local IP? Must be the same AFAIK.

When using loopback adress in C#, you do not need to look it up. Just use `IPAddress.Loopback`.

other than that, theres nothing wrong with your server.

A side note:

```
um.maintainUserModel(); //method uses to maintain user model
```

*Please* do not write comments like that. It's just a duplication of the actual code. It doesn't add any value, all it do is cluttering the code file.

### Update

This script connects fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function examplePageLoad(event) {
        if ("WebSocket" in window) {
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:13000/");
            ws.onopen = function() {
                alert('Sending');
                ws.send("message to send");
            }
            ws.onmessage = function (evt) { 
                alert('Received: ' + evt.data);
            };
            ws.onclose = function() { // websocket is closed. 
            };

            alert('readystate: ' + ws.readyState + " for " + ws.URL);
        }
        else
            alert('Not supported');
    }

    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("load", examplePageLoad, true);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: still the same problem i'm afraid

Comment: try to use your real ip both in the browser and in the server. Try to connect to the server using telnet.

Comment: when I write the loopback ip with port in the browser, it works, the server receives a request. It's just that when I am calling it from the script, it doesn't. I checked, the event is valid, when a new tab is loaded, the event is initiated, but the server remains waiting for a connection

Comment: I'm unsure of the loopback address. Please use your real ip.

Comment: I tried that too :(. Thanks for your help, don't worry. I must have something wrong in my javascript code

Comment: the add your complete javascript, as you do not do anything with the websocket in the code that you included.

Comment: I;m really frustrated, I can't seem to find any tutorials or examples of how to do this and I am a bit lost